# I have not idea how this is working for the youtube person and not for me, even after copying their code from github

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, lombok

I have been teaching myself Spring Boot and have started learning joins and table relationships. I have been following along with the YouTuber java techie's instructions on this video (SpringBoot : Spring Data JPA - https://youtu.be/8qhaDBCJh6I). At one point in the video he has

```
package com.javatechie.jpa.dto;

import com.javatechie.jpa.entity.Customer;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class OrderRequest {

   private Customer customer;
}
```

He later called this class

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @PostMapping("/placeOrder")
    public Customer placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequest request){
       return customerRepository.save(request.getCustomer());
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is working for him. he is calling the getCustomer function without ever defining the function in the OrderRequest Class. But in his video he is able to run everything without issue, sending the JSON file through to the SQL table. Indeed when i have tried to do it, EVEN with his own code from GitHub (https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/spring-data-jpa-one2many-join-example.git) eclipse is telling me that no getCustomer function exists and i am constantly getting the 500 error saying, again, that the getCustomer function does not exist.

What am i doing wrong? Is it using Eclipse instead of Intelli-J ? I cannot wrap my head around why it is not working even with his own code from GitHub. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The author is using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). That project reduces boilerplate but works by hacking into the compiler. I've never used it, but it's possible you have to configure Eclipse and/or IntelliJ to recognize/use Lombok.

Comment: You have to enable annotation processing. Also you can download Lombok plugin.

Comment: I didnt know that you had to install an add on to use Lombok, i was under the impression just having it in the pom would work. I will try again after adding Lombok to eclipse, thanks for the advice.:)

Comment: @Data lombok annotation is automatically  provide getter and setter for the all fields

Answer (score 0):

Because Customer is a your Class, you need to implement a method GetCustomer in OrderRequest Class.
You can use Lombok or create a manual Get and Set function for every attribute, so:

```
    package com.javatechie.jpa.dto;

import com.javatechie.jpa.entity.Customer;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class OrderRequest {

   private Customer customer;

public setCustomer(Customer customer){
  this.customer = customer;
}

public getCustomer(){
  return this.customer;
}
}
```

Comment: The OP has Lombok annotations and should be generating the getter and setter automatically.

Comment: Yes, but the OP already has Lombok annotations. Indicating something else is wrong.

Comment: Try to use '@Getter' and '@Setter' annotation

Answer (score 0):

`@data` lombok will **implicitly** create all : **getter**+setter+constructor etc ..  => There should be no error when hes calling `getCustomer()`, because he annotated Class `OrderRequest` with `@data` so the getters and setters will be created implicitly.

Here is the official what lombok official site said about  lombok

> @Data is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor together

So it is apparent that you have problem installing lombok in eclipse  ..I would recommend Dropping lombok and creating setter,getter and constructors yourself as a start.

I hope I helped

Comment: I have already gotten it working by manually creating the constructors and getters and setters, that was the first thing i did when i could not get his code to work. At this point i just want to get to the bottom of why its working for him and not for me. Thanks for the help